# Select items from List of structs

Tags: c#, linq, list

I've got List of sctructs. In struct there is field x. I would like to select those of structs, which are rather close to each other by parameter x. In other words, I'd like to clusterise them by x.
I guess, there should be one-line solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will this be clustering in the graph sense, where if {A, B}, {B, C}, and {C, D} are all close then all four get clustered together even though A and D are not particularly close? Or should all members of a cluster be close to each other?

Comment: It's not "clustering". It's called "grouping". In SQL: `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 4):

If I understood correctly what you want, then you might need to sort your list by the structure's field X.

Comment: Yeah, I can sort them, and then pairwise compare the difference between them, but I suggest, there might a standard function or something like that

Answer (score 2):

Look at the `GroupBy` extension method:

```
var items = mylist.GroupBy(c => c.X);
```

[This article](http://www.formatexception.com/2009/03/linq-group-by-and-groupby/) gives a lot of examples using `group by`.

Comment: this does not cluster, it groups them by equal Xs

Comment: Well he could group by X and then iterate over the IGrouping, merging the collections that are sufficiently "close" enough to each other.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing graph-style clustering, the easiest way to do it is by building up a list of clusters which is initially empty.  Then loop over the input and, for each value, find all of the clusters which have at least one element which is close to the current value.  All those clusters should then be merged together with the value.  If there aren't any, then the value goes into a cluster all by itself.

Here is some sample code for how to do it with a simple list of integers.

```
IEnumerable<int> input;
int threshold;

List<List<int>> clusters = new List<List<int>>();

foreach(var current in input)
{
    // Search the current list of clusters for ones which contain at least one
    // entry such that the difference between it and x is less than the threshold
    var matchingClusters = 
        clusters.Where(
            cluster => cluster.Any(
                           val => Math.Abs(current - val) <= threshold)
        ).ToList();

    // Merge all the clusters that were found, plus x, into a new cluster.
    // Replace all the existing clusters with this new one.
    IEnumerable<int> newCluster = new List<int>(new[] { current });
    foreach (var match in matchingClusters)
    {
        clusters.Remove(match);
        newCluster = newCluster.Concat(match);
    }
    clusters.Add(newCluster.ToList());
}
```